# How to select a particular record and to set it to textView - Android SQlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have the following code ! The SelectTable is not working as of now. All I need to do is to Pick a particular record from the database and to change the TextView of that to the record that is selected .
I.E.,
textView1.setText
textView.setText
should set it to the name and place of the selected record ! 
Please Help !

```
package com.example.sqlitedemo;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout Linear;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
private static String DBNAME = "PERSONS.db";    /
private static String TABLE = "MY_TABLE";       
TextView textView1,textView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Creating table.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dropTable();        // DROPPING THE TABLE.
            createTable();

            insertIntoTable();
            selectTable();
            //showTableValues();

        }

        public void createTable(){
            try{
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, PLACE TEXT);");
            mydb.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in creating table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
        // THIS FUNCTION INSERTS DATA TO THE DATABASE
        public void insertIntoTable(){
            try{
                mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('CODERZHEAVEN','GREAT INDIA')");
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('ANTHONY','USA')");
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('SHUING','JAPAN')");
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('JAMES','INDIA')");
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('SOORYA','INDIA')");
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('MALIK','INDIA')");
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('myname','America')");
                mydb.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }

        public void selectTable(){
            try{
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            String q = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE ID = '1'";
            //String name = c.getString(c.getColumnName(0));
            //String place = c.getString(c.getColumnName(1));
            Cursor mCursor = mydb.rawQuery(q, null);
            String name = mCursor.getString(0);
            String place = mCursor.getString(1);
            textView1.setText(name);
            textView.setText(place);

            mydb.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error selecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }

        }

        public void dropTable(){
            try{
                mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                mydb.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE);

                mydb.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error encountered while dropping.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    }

xml Layout :


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the app crashing, or is it just not updating the record? Also, do String name and String place have values in them, or are there just empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have create table query as follows,

```
mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, PLACE TEXT);");
```

Here your ID is in INTEGER format while in select query you are accessing it as Id = "1", which is wrong.

To correct this you need to make following corrections.

- First of all make your ID to AUTOINCREMENT as follows,

  ```
  mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, PLACE TEXT);");
  ```
- Change your select query as follows,

  ```
  String q = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE ID = 1";
  ```
- After this statement `Cursor mCursor = mydb.rawQuery(q, null);` write following statement,

  ```
  mCursor.moveToFirst();
  ```

Since you need to modify the create table query, I suggest you to remove your old application and install fresh one, otherwise it will not give proper output.

Comment: Thankyou ! I changed it to this : String q = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE NAME = 'ANTHONY'"; How do I set PLACE of this record into the textview ?

Comment: That part you have already done with these statements `textView1.setText(name);`

Comment: @user3496326, glad to hear that, You can accept my answer by ticking green mark besides my answer :)

Comment: Yea Thank you :) Been trying that 20 More seconds ;) !